# Accessing internally hosted server inside Docker container from docker host

Tags: javascript, docker, express, networking

So my question is a bit different, I've looked at the existing answers but couldn't find a solution.
So I have a simple express.js application which looks like:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
const PORT = 8080;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  var params = req.params;
  var url = req.query["url"];
  res.send('<h1>Hello ' + url + '</h1>');
});
app.listen(PORT, HOST, () => console.log(`App running on ${PORT}`));
```

If I dockerize this application and expose and bind my port then I am able to access the application but within the docker container apart from this app, I want to parallel run a Python HTTPServer using the command `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 1337` and I want that it should only be accessible through my container only `http://dockerip:8080/?url=<iframe src = "http://0.0.0.0.0:1337"></iframe>` but it fails to connect to port 1337. If I expose 1337, then obviously it will be accessible via `http://dockerip:1337` which I don't want.

What can I do to make it accessible ONLY from within the docker container.

Comment: You could use a docker network in wich you put your two services and only expose the node service and not the python one. This would be easier when you use docker compose to set it up. Btw I don't think your Iframe example makes any sense as the browser of the client will reqeust the iframe src url instead of your node application.

Comment: That is what I was asking, is there any way to access the internal server through iframe src? If I try to do `iframe src="0.0.0.0:1337"`  will that not resolve the docker container's localhost ip technically the server one?

Comment: If the internal server is accessible through iframe src it will also be accessible without an iframe directly. You could proxy the requests to the internal server through your other container so that the internal service is only reachable through that proxy

Comment: `If the internal server is accessible through iframe src it will also be accessible without an iframe directly.` Yeah that means basically what I am doing is exposing the server as well that is what I don't want to do.

Comment: Okay what if I don't use docker for this and just do `node app.js` on a cloud VM instance and parallely host a python server on the VM. I expose the nodeJS app port but not the python server one, then also it is not accessible. I think does it mean that I cannot load anything in iframe that isn't exposed or "publically" reachable?

Comment: Yes exactly this is not a docker problem per se